# SignalR accessTokenFactory doesn't pass token to request query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, signalr

I'm trying to access token on SignalRHub class via query string.
Here is client code:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl($("#url").val(), {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
    accessTokenFactory: () => {
       token                                         
    }
  })
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
  .build();
```

Jwt Configuration :

```
OnMessageReceived = context =>
{
var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.Equals("/websocket"))
{
 context.Token = accessToken;
}
 return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Problem is when i make a request to my hub, the accessToken is null, even if i'm passing it via accessTokenFactory. There is no query string parameter "access_token". Code was made following [docs guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2). I already tried to change my middleware invocation in startup and didn't resolve.

Startup file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
   services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
   .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

   /*aditional configurations*/

   services.AddSignalR();

   /*more aditional configurations*/

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseCors(options =>
   {
    options.WithExposedHeaders("Location");
    options.AllowAnyOrigin();
    options.AllowAnyHeader();
    options.AllowAnyMethod();
    options.AllowCredentials();
   });

   app.UseSignalR(routes =>
   {
    routes.MapHub<SignalRHub>("/websocket");
   });

   app.UseAuthentication();

   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
    routes.MapRoute("api", "{controller}/{action}/{id}");
   });

   /*aditional middlewares*/

   app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
   {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |          
    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
   });

}
```

Any help will be apreciated

Comment: It needs to be `accessTokenFactory: () => { return token }` or just `accessTokenFactory: () => token`.

Comment: Indeed it was the `return` keyword that was missing... i'm feeling extremely dumb right now... thank you !

Comment: gonna leave it here for my future self have good laughs... classic first question on SO

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not actually providing the token in your accessTokenFactory implementation. You need to return the token value or else your HubConnection won't get it

```
accessTokenFactory: () => {
   return token                                         
}
```